# Accessing an anchor element using name attribute with jQuery

Tags: jquery, attributes, tags, anchor

I like to access an anchor (a) element with a specific name in jQuery to obtain its position. I tried the following:

HTML:

```
<a name="test">An anchor.</a>
```

JavaScript:

```
var top = $("a [name=test]").position().top;
```

Returns empty object.

```
var top = $("a").position().top;
```

and

```
var top = $("[name=test]").position().top;
```

finds it. How do I write it to get an anchor element with name "test"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need space after `a` in your selector:

```
var top = $("a[name=test]").position().top;
```

If you put space then it'll find the child elements with name `test` of any anchor instead.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the space :

```
var top = $("a[name=test]").position().top;
```

A space indicates that you're looking for a child element.